# If $A \in B$ and $B \subseteq C$, how can I prove $A \in C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an intuitive understanding of why this is, and I can also do this using example sets. I know this is true because B being a subset of C means that every element in B is also in C, but I am not sure how to translate this into logical statements. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a definition of $B\subseteq C$? Have you tried using that?

Comment: It's the definition.  It can't not be true.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, $B \subseteq C$ means $\forall x, x \in B \implies x \in C$

Since $A \in B$, from the above, we have $A \in C$.

Answer (score 0):

We usually denote elements of sets with lowercase letters and sets with uppercase letters, so I will write $a \in B$ instead of $A \in B$ [1]. In other words, we will show that if $a \in B$ and $B \subset C$, then $a \in C$. The proof is more or less a direct translation of your intuition.

If $B \subset C$, then any $b \in B$ is also in $C$, by definition. By assumption, $a \in B$, whence $a \in C$ also, giving the desired result.

You can translate this into logic notation, if you would like, but this is a perfectly good proof. Indeed, most mathematical proofs are written like this rather than in logic notation.

[1] If you actually meant to write $A \subset B$, not $A \in B$, then the proof is similarly easy.